# Better way for batch insert in Java / mysql? Insert table values(...), (...)? Or preparedStatement.addBatch()

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to implement batch insert into mysql db in my java code. My colleagues implement using

```
insert table_a (col1, col2 ...) values (val1, val2 ...), (val12, val22)...
```

I am thinking using `preparedStatement.addBatch()` for each insert row, cause the first way will fail all inserts if one value is bad. But I am wondering if it will slow down the performance. cause it seems it run insert one by one ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exact mechanism for how batching will work under the hood is left to the JDBC driver implementation - but every DB I've ever used has shown performance improvements using it! If you do several tx's of 10k inserts using individual statements vs. batching and attach a profiler, I'd wager you'll see markedly better performance from the latter! Just double check your driver supports "partially complete" batch inserts. SUCCESS_NO_INFO might be returned by some and you're left in limbo - forcing you to rollback (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Comment: *the first way will fail all inserts if one value is bad*... I can't speak for your case, but often that's preferred.